# Changing iframe src via drop down menu doesn't load new iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, src

I played around with a few examples on here, but I can't seem to load the new iframe without "resetting" the drop down menu (choosing the "pick resort" option that has no value).  Is there a way to dynamically change the iframe once a new option is selected?

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/scdgw48g/

```
<h2>Your Powder Forecast</h2>
<p>Pick a location to see who's getting hit!</p>
<select id="selectResort">
<option>Pick Resort</option>
<option value="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=42.3583&lon=-71.0603&name=Downtown Boston&font=inherit">Boston</option>
<option value="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=39.6061&lon=-106.3571&name=Vail&font=inherit">Vail</option>
</select>
<button onClick="loadPages()">See Forecast</button>

<iframe id="myFrame" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src=""> </iframe>

 <script>
    var urlSelect = document.getElementById('selectResort'),
    myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    function loadPages() {
    var loc = urlSelect.value;
    // You can also do -> myFrame.src = loc;
    myFrame.setAttribute('src', loc);
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: If you check your console for that fiddle it is saying the function is undefined when you click the button.

Comment: Works in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykdug757/ if you select `no wrap in body` option when you add jQuery on the left toolbar. Should work in your webpage too.

Answer (score 2):

First set `src = ""`, then after a minimal delay, set it to `src` you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/scdgw48g/3/

```
function loadPages() {
    myFrame.src = "";
    setTimeout(function () {
        myFrame.src = urlSelect.value;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Could you point me to where `urlSelect.value` is how one read select option values?

Comment: @LGSon - The `value` property of the `HTMLSelectElement` interface is defined in the [DOM Level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919), and documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535893(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Many thanks, been using the old way for so long and completely missed this one. The `text` property though, is still the old way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an argument to one of your URLs to differentiate them from one another. I think the browser is seeing them as the same URL, since they both start with `http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=`. Try the following. Notice how I added `?different` to the second URL:

```
<option value="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=42.3583&lon=-71.0603&name=Downtown Boston&font=inherit">Boston</option>
<option value="http://forecast.io/embed/?different#lat=39.6061&lon=-106.3571&name=Vail&font=inherit">Vail</option>
```

This may also be of interest, although I don't think it applies in your case:

Some websites do not allow themselves to be loaded into an iframe. They do this by setting the [X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). When I changed your `http://forecast.io` URLs to `http://apple.com` and `http://rogers.com`, everything worked fine. However, when I changed them to `http://google.com` and `http://microsoft.com`, Chrome threw the following error. This is because the Microsoft and Google websites do not allow themselves to be loaded into an iframe on an external website.

`Refused to display 'http://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`